# How to use multiple countries in MapKit search?

Tags: swift

I have a code that searches and finds addresses in my app. this works fine.

But it only works in 1 country. and I have to hardcode the country name like 'Germany' or 'United States' in my code which is not ideal.

I was wondering if I could use multiple country name?

My current code looks like this:

```
  self.locationResults = results.filter { $0.subtitle.contains("United States") }
```

I tried to use an OR clause but that doesn't seem to work.

I tried this:

```
 self.locationResults = results.filter { $0.subtitle.contains("Germany" | "United States") }
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for ‘or’ two countries in your example is wrong. You need to execute the `contains` method for each country. Here is a simple Playground that has enough code to quickly show how to do that and could help other people with different answers:

```
struct Result {
    let subtitle: String
}

let results: [Result] = [Result(subtitle: "France"), Result(subtitle: "Germany"),
                         Result(subtitle: "Spain"), Result(subtitle: "The United States of America")]

// Hard coding a few countries is one approach
let locationResults = results.filter { $0.subtitle.contains("Germany")
    || $0.subtitle.contains("United States")
}
print(locationResults)
```

That gets a bit messy if you need to add more countries. A better solution is to have an array of countries to search for:

```
// A better approach would be to list the countries separately (this could be
// generated at run time rather than be hard-coded as in this example)
let countries = ["Germany", "United States", "Italy", "France"]
locationResults = results.filter { result in
    countries.contains { country in
        result.subtitle.contains(country)
    }
}
print(locationResults)
```

This checks each of the result subtitles to see if it contains any of the country names.